# Correct use of Silkscreen Layer and Documentation Layer

Tags: silkscreen

I'm looking to understand how correctly design my board silkscreen. I usually used to draw silkscreen of exact size of my package, especially for SMD parts, to easly know their dimentions and allow me to correctly place them on my BRD.

Something like this for through hole package:

[image]

I've seen it's used, but someone use this:

[image]

My tought was, it's correct to use silk for exact size of package and doc just for placement? So in Doc I can place bigger squares for easy reading in placing moment of small SMD?

Comment: You make your silk screen however you want. If it makes sense to the builder and tester then there is no problem.

Comment: For small SMD parts, I wouldn't make the silkscreen the same size as the part. I'd make it bigger so the part doesn't get lifted off its pads by the silkscreen ink.